# Getting the location using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to figure out how to output the location of the twitter user only if they have it displayed. How would I go about doing that? Right now I have this:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time
import json
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

ckey = ''
csecret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print status.text
        if status.coordinates:
            print 'coords:', status.coordinates
        if status.place:
            print 'place:', status.place.full_name

        return True

    on_event = on_status

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["twerk"])
```

Edit: it's giving an error for the last line of code. How could I filter the word "twerk" or "miley"

So it's currently outputting a tweet if the tweet consists of the words twerk or miley, but I would like to get the coordinates of that tweet only if they have it displayed. I thought it would be something like tweet = data.coordinates, but that is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: You should be aware that not many users have geo-location enabled. So not all of your tweets will have the coordinates. It's entirely possible none of them will have it.

Comment: That's completely fine with me, IanAuldi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use string manipulation when you can just load the JSON as a Python object, using [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser


def on_data(self, data):
    data = json.loads(HTMLParser().unescape(data))
    tweet = data['text']
    print tweet
    return True
```

This also gives you access to the other [fields of the Tweet object](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets), such as the coordinates:

```
if data['coordinates']:
    print data['coordinates']
```

or the place object:

```
if data.get('place'):
    print data['place']['full_name']
```

For the streaming API, you may want to **not** override the `on_data()` method and instead use the `on_event()` or `on_status()` handlers; the default `on_data()` implementation loads the JSON and passes on a parsed Tweepy object to those handlers:

```
class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print status.text
        if status.coordinates:
            print 'coords:', status.coordinates
        if status.place:
            print 'place:', status.place.full_name

        return True

    on_event = on_status

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status
```

I see messages like:

```
Ainda sonho com uma apresentação de twerk ao vivo  #8BieberManiaNaZonaLivreFM #MTVHottest Justin Bieber
coords: {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-49.319543, -16.679431]}
place: Goiânia, Goiás
```

Fly by with the above listener.

Comment: So, wait, nothing is printing out right now. Any idea what I am doing wrong. I'll edit my original post with what I have.

Comment: If I don't include the last line of code on my edit it will compile it just won't grab any tweets at all. How could I filter the words?

Comment: @Mdjon26: I certainly see messages printed using the stream listener with specific `on_event` and `on_status` handlers.

Comment: Hmmm interesting. It appears to be working for about 30 seconds and then it'll get this error. "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 20-22: original not in range(128)" any idea how to fix that? I edited the original post with what I have.

Comment: @Mdjon26: your console cannot handle Unicode characters it appears. Many tweets use Emoji and other Unicode characters.

Comment: Ohh.. perhaps because I am using an online compiler to do this? that would be the error?

Comment: @Mdjon26: An online Python console may indeed not be configured to handle anything but ASCII text being printed.