# Older tweets Tweepy using Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to get older tweet data (approximately 2 months old) using tweepy in Python. I tried since and until parameters but no success. Has anyone got a work around in tweepy or some other API.

```
for id,tweet in enumerate (tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='SpecificWord', since="2016-04-26", until="2016-04-28", lang="en", include_retweets=False    ).items(200)):
     #Write a row to the csv file
     CSVW.writerow([tweet.created_at,    tweet.retweet_count,    tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. [The docs on the Twitter API are very clear](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search):

> The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days.

There is no way to search back further than that.

Comment: Thanks Terence, do you recommend any open source website from where I can download the historical tweet data based on 'SpecificWord' and then use that for further analysis?

Comment: The only place to get historical data is https://www.gnip.com/ - or start gathering the data today :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways to get older tweets.

1. You get the forked version of Tweepy, which supports multiple authentication handlers. [Here is an instruction](http://www.nirg.net/using-tweepy.html) on how to use it (unfortunately only with Python 2.7). Or you use [this ratetime](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/484) limiter for Tweepy. But with the Twitter API the oldest data you can get is about 7 days I think.
2. The other way is to use [GetOldTweets-python](https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python), it also works with Python 3. Here is an example on how to use it.

First Install lxml (Version 3.5) & pyquery Version 1.2.10):

```
pip3 install lxml==3.5.0
pip3 install pyquery==1.2.10
```

Then download GetOldTweets-python and copy the folder got3 into you site packages folder and run Python.

```
import got3

max_tweets = 3

tweetCriteria = got3.manager.TweetCriteria().setUntil("2016-01-31").setQuerySearch("bitcoin").setMaxTweets(max_tweets)

for i in range(max_tweets):
    tweet = got3.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)[i]
    print(tweet.id)
    print(tweet.username)
    print(tweet.text)
    print(tweet.date)
```

Now you are getting Tweets from 2016!

```
693584301917655041
bitcoinfirehose
Teenagers are using untraceable currency Bitcoin to buy dangerous drugs online http://ift.tt/20eIDwU #reddit #bitcoin
2016-01-31 00:59:18

693584300265070593
bitcoinfirehose
Hey guys I've seen a need to cashout to Visa. So I created a site to get moneypak codes via Bitcoin ! Please come check it out! …
2016-01-31 00:59:18

693584286210002944
b1eedr
Bitcoin 2.0: Fantasy Or Inevitability? https://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/bitcoin-2-0-fantasy-or-inevitability/ @CryptoCoinsNews
2016-01-31 00:59:14
```

Comment: Can we get tweets from a specific location (geocoding) with GeoOldTweets?

Comment: I didn't try it, but maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224692/getting-the-location-using-tweepy#25224707

Comment: Hey! does collecting tweets this way breach twitter policy in any way? I found this ***You also agree not to misuse our Services, for example, by interfering with them or accessing them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide*** in Twitter Terms of Service https://twitter.com/en/tos.