# Tweepy api.search, how to get the tweets older than 10 days?

Tags: tweepy

If you add a phrase to search for option "until", it is easy to discover that the twitter API gives tweets are not older than 10 days:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrlZT.png)

Today, September 29th, and the last tweet received 19!

Example code:

```
api = tw_oauth('./auth.k')

def limit_handled(cursor):
    while True:
        try:
            yield cursor.next()
        except tweepy.RateLimitError:
            time.sleep(15 * 60)

for tweet in limit_handled(tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='python until:2016-09-20', count = 20).items()):
    print (tweet.id, tweet.created_at)
```

**How do I get tweets older than 10 days?**

For example, if you need a lot of tweets Spars (more than the daily limit, and allows you to have to interrupt the process).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Older tweets Tweepy using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017903/older-tweets-tweepy-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. [The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days.](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)