# How to get old tweets by tweet-ID using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I was using Tweepy, but as I discovered in the link ([Older tweets Tweepy using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017903/older-tweets-tweepy-using-python)) I cannot get older tweets using tweppy.

I found some libraries to get older tweets, but I cannot get them by their IDs.

Someone knows how can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use tweepy to find tweets no matter how old they are using `get_status()`

## example

```
# import tweepy
import tweepy

# api keys from twitter developers
consumer_key='<your consumer_key here>'
consumer_secret='<your consumer_secret here>'
access_token='<your access_token here>'
acess_token_sectret='<your acess_token_sectret here>'

# login to twitter 
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, acess_token_sectret)
auth.secure = True
api = tweepy.API(auth)



# define the id of the tweet you are looking for
id = 1181329749966295041

# get the tweet
tweet = api.get_status(id)
# print the text of the tweet
print(tweet.text)
```